# Is there a more eloquent way to write a string and symbol replacement in javascript where order matters?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, replace, symbols

I have few sets of strings that I am consuming and stripping all symbols besides a few away. I then have to replace the (spaces) with %20 once a promise is returned. I have a solution working for now (minus the promise for an easier problem to understand)

```
let ABC = "asvue ? ?. @@";

console.log(ABC
.replace(/[?]/g,'\?')
.replace(/[.]/g,'\.')
.replace(/[@]/g,'\@')
.replace(/[^a-zA-Z @.?]/g,'_')
.replace(/ /g,'%20'));
```

This gives the correct results `"asvue%20?%20?.%20@@"` but is there a better or more eloquent way to right this? Also I know the regex is not necessary but it is just an old habit of mine.

Comment: so ... all you want to do is replace space with `%20`? seems like an awful lot of replacing happening ... for `ABC.replace(/ /g, '%20')`

Comment: `()=>{String.toCharCode(0)}` makes no sense, that just returns `undefined`.

Comment: Did you mean to put a backslash in front of `?`, `.` and `@` characters? If so, you'll need to string-escape the backslash. And it's much easier done with `.replace(/[?.@]/g, "\\$&")`. Currently, you're replacing `?` with `?`, `.` with `.`, and `@` with `@`, which does nothing and the code could just be dropped.

Comment: if you want to prepare the string for a link you can use `escape(ABC)`, if you want to replace any kind of "space" (space, line return, etc) `ABC.replace(/\s+/g, '%20')`

Comment: Are you trying to encode URI's ? if yes just use `encodeURI("asvue ? ?. @@")`

Comment: Thank you all for all of your insight so far, @Jaromanda X I am also replacing all other characters ``` .replace(/[^a-zA-Z @?.]/g, "_"); ``` in the string besides those three characters. and yes it does seem a bit excessive that is why I asked for all of your wisdom

Comment: @Bergi yes that is useless now I was using it for something else at first my apologies

Comment: @ mars073 I never new that the ``` escape() ``` function existed in other languages I leaned so hard on regex. honestly I think these may be my solution.

Comment: @CodeManiac I am not actually encoding an URI thank you

Comment: @JewellSimon [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) is deprecated, you should use `encodeURIComponent` instead.

Comment: @Bergi thank you sir/madam, this actually works fantastically that ``` ? ``` are being handled by encodeURIComponent.  This significantly reduces the complexity of the module. Could you post so I can mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi said, you should use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), which is "replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character".

```js
let ABC = "asvue ? ?. @@";
console.log(encodeURIComponent(ABC));  // 'asvue%20%3F%20%3F.%20%40%40'
```